# Codeigniter file upload - filename checking

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload

I am working with uploading files in codeigniter, my problem is coming from that I have to file inputs, they are there to upload a file that is used by staff members and a file that cusstomers will see (sensitive data has been removed).

The client is going to be uploading the files name in this convention,

```
filename_parsed.pdf
filename_unparsed.pdf
```

How would I go about checking that the filename finishes with an `_parsed` or `_unparsed`?

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has a helper function for files...make sure the file helper is loaded

`$var = get_file_info('path/to/file','name')`

```
if(strpos($var,'_unparsed') !== false) {
    // Do stuff
} else if(strpos($var,'_parsed') !== false) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/(_(un|)parsed)$/', $file_name))
{
    //tests for:
    // _unparsed
    // _parsed

    //Important not to include the file ext otherwise will fail
}
```